# How do I upload a file into ArcCatalog?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, mac, arccatalog, citrix

I am trying to upload a photo into a folder in ArcCatalog, yet I haven't been able to find where and how to do that.

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 (ArcGIS for Desktop) through my school's Citrix receiver.

I have a MacBook which apparently does not work with ArcGIS very well?

Comment: ArcCatalog isn't a container, so nothing could be uploaded "into" it.  Its companion application, ArcMap, is a viewing application (it can't be uploaded into either, but it can view certain kinds of imagery).  Please **edit** the question to provide more details, including the exact software release(s) in use, and a longer description of what data you have an what you're trying to archieve.

Comment: Also, ArcGIS for Desktop is not supported on Mac, ["Please note that ArcGIS for Desktop is not certified or supported on the Mac operating system"](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-desktop/system-requirements). Are you using a Windows VM on your macbook?

Comment: FYI: You can use Parallels to use ArcCatalog (in windows on a mac) https://www.parallels.com/ca/products/desktop/

Comment: Given the presence of Citrix, the "upload" process is likely completely unrelated to GIS, and this question would be better directed to your school IT department or TA/professor.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used ArcCatalog for a year or so but as far as I remember you don't 'upload' a file to it.  You connect to a folder (which you seem to have done) and if a partcular file is not visible, that is probably because it is not in a format handled by Arccatalog so is not of any interest to it, therefore not visible - or if it is a suitable format - but you may need to click refresh on the folder connection - e.g. if you just moved the file to the folder in question, the folder contents listing may need to be refreshed - right click on the folder and select *Refresh*